# How to highlight current id element in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to highlight current '#id' fragment:

Like if the URL is : `http://localhost:4321/store/zapakshop/#943`

then id=943 should be highlighted..

I have tried this but it is not working:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window.location.hash).effect("highlight", {
        color: "#FF0000"
    }, 3000);       
    });
```

Help me...

Comment: What is `.effect()` method?

Comment: yes i know it is wrong....i tried something i found on net...

Comment: @ArtyomNeustroev I'm guessing it's http://jqueryui.com/effect/

Comment: @ArtyomNeustroev is it this: http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Highlight

Comment: Are you including jquery UI?

Comment: This is a method from jQueryUI packet. It should be loaded on your page in order to work. Syntax looks fine.

Comment: Do you have jQuery UI referenced in your HTML page? Do you have any error messages in your browsers console window?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Yes it is working but it is changing the color permanently i just want a flash... – user2217267

[Snook](http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/yellow-fade-technique-css-animations) has a nice example of doing this with CSS3. Here is a working example, adapted from that page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<style type="text/css" media="all">
:target {
    -webkit-animation: target-fade 3s 1;
    -moz-animation: target-fade 3s 1;
}

@-webkit-keyframes target-fade {
    0% { background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.1); }
    100% { background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0); }
}

@-moz-keyframes target-fade {
    0% { background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.1); }
    100% { background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0); }
}
</style>

</head>

<body>
<p>Click the link to <a href="#goal">target the div</a>.


<div id="goal">This is the div. This is the div. This is the div. This is the div. This is the div. This is the div. This is the div. This is the div. This is the div. This is the div. This is the div. This is the div. This is the div. This is the div. This is the div. This is the div. This is the div. This is the div. This is the div. This is the div. This is the div. This is the div. This is the div. This is the div. </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to include jquery UI after you have included jquery itself:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is the only sensible answer here, +1

Comment: This highlights the full URL, the requirement is just to highlight `943`

Comment: Now console is showing this error `Uncaught TypeError: Object function ( selector, context ) {
  // The jQuery object is actually just the init constructor 'enhanced'
  return new jQuery.fn.init( selector, context );
 } has no method 'isPlainObject'`

Answer (score 2):

You might use the target pseudo class in your CSS. This highlights the element with the ID that's currently present as a hash on the URL.

```
*:target {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/css/%3Atarget

Answer (score 0):

If you're just applying style to the element with the same ID as the hash in your URL, you can do that via the `target` pseudo selector:

```
:target {
   color:#f00;
}
```

Source: http://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/t/target/

Sacha beat me to it, but I'll leave my link to the CSS tricks article that explains this pseudo selector so well.

Comment: Yes it is working but it is changing the color permanently i just want a flash...

Comment: Do you know whether the browsers you need to support are capable of transitions? See http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-transitions

Answer (score 0):

I did that using

```
document.getElementById(id).style.outline = 'red solid 3px';
```

this works for all elements that have an outline (like a textarea). If you want to flash this up for 100 ms, your next line can be:

```
window.setTimeout(unoutline, 100);
```

and you will define a function unoutline like this:

```
function unoutline()
{
  document.getElementById(id).style.outline = '';
}
```

You can see the code in action on http://www.staerk.de/regex.